# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, reporting-services, web-config, ssrs-2008

I have SSRS reports in my project.
All reports are working perfectly.  but only one report is not working on production server
, working on local .

Error Msg;

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Plz help ....no findings on this because it is working on local but gives error on server..

Comment: need help guys ..............

Comment: what does that report have that is different from the others? That error usually happens when the SSRS server doesn't "see" the DB server (either by firewall blocking, or being on a different network)

Comment: all reprots are same. sql query for this report is taking 2-3 minutes to run on sql .

Comment: all suggestion welcome ........... I already increased httprequest execution time to 30 mins

Comment: You are supposed to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and see if Microsoft support team can assist. Without accessing your environment, it is impossible to tell what is the root cause.

Comment: This question is not answerable, there's too little detail to be able to help without resorting to guessing. You should provide more details, specifically explain what you've tried to resolve this issue yourself and what problems you ran in to. Note that you can (and should) edit your question with additional details; don't use comments for that (or for trying to bump it, for that matter - that's what the [bounty system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) is for).

Answer (score 2):

This is a configuration setting on the SQL server :

1. rt click on SQL server instance and go to properties
2. choose connections
3. change remote query timeout